# TypeScript. Наследование от класса с generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-типы

TypeScript. Мне нужно, чтобы SomeController был построен на базе BaseController со спецификой некоторого типа SomeModel. Пробовал сделать как-то так:

```
class SomeModel {
    static methodOfModel() {}
}
class BaseController <T> {
    index() {
        T.methodOfModel()   
     // SomeModel.methodOfModel() works
    }
}
class SomeController extends BaseController<SomeModel> {}
new SomeController()
```

Получаю ошибку *'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.*

Comment: ну да. Т - тип, так нельзя T.methodOfModel()

Comment: а как можно? :)

Comment: компилятор не знает что это за тип а если уточнить что T extends KnowType

Comment: и T.methodOfModel() статический метод в KnowType

Comment: То думаю вы сможете вызвать этот метод. Иначе откуда узнать существует ли метод

Comment: Тайпсрипта нет в рантайме. Мысленно уберите из вашего кода все типы и попробуйте ответь на вопрос откуда JS возьмёт `SomeModel`?

Comment: @AlexeyTen немного уточню. Нет статической типизации. All valid JavaScript code is also TypeScript code. https://www.typescriptlang.org/

Comment: Может надо что-то такое? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBJwM4FkJgBYD2AJsgN4CwAUMjcgLa6FEDyMWxEANgFzIBiAVxAIwwAiADcVAL5UqCTpgzIAygQbsiXMlVrIMYOKIT1GxVpq4AKAJRlZlB-MUZlahgGFxYKAU6doZAAeABVkCAAPSBAiZXRsMyIAPh1qWgRxAygBEQIoKwAHKGAANyMUOg4eZBC7Uic0mlAtCNtUvT18YAwAOkqtTj7EiyrbKUbkBwaMkANkEwBeZBAIAHdVdQgvcF9-aCt3CEtOG3GEHubIseQAehvkQCQQQGkQQHYQJ8AmEEAGEEBWEEAhEA2NFUhvhzGxRjYqEA

Comment: @AlexeyTen, так не выйдет, потому что реализация SomeModel в проекте спрятана во внешней библиотеке

Comment: Не вижу в этом никакой проблемы

Comment: @AlexeyTen, к тому же SomeModel может быть заменен на другой класс с таким же родителем (в первом примере я не указал, что  SomeModel унаследован от другого класса)

Comment: Всё ещё не вижу проблемы передать в конструктор что угодно, лишь бы у него был нужный метод

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил вопрос так:

```
class SomeModel {
    static methodOfModel() {}
}
class BaseController {
    someModel: typeof SomeModel
    constructor(someModel: typeof SomeModel){
        this.someModel = someModel
    }
    index() {
        this.someModel.methodOfModel()   
    }
}
class SomeController extends BaseController {
    constructor() {
        super(SomeModel)
    }
}
new SomeController()
```

Comment: Практически ровно это я и написал

Comment: Да, идею использовать конструктор я взял у вас. Меня просто смутило использование интерфейса в вашем примере

Comment: Правильно, но generic можно было оставить.